# Find the rank of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 &1 &0 &1 \\ 1 &2 &2 &1 \\ 3 &4 &2 &3 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Found this exercise in Serge Lang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*:

> Find the rank of the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &1 &0 &1 \\ 1 &2 &2 &1 \\ 3 &4 &2 &3 \end{pmatrix}$$

---

So my process to solve it is as follows. First, I set a system

$$ x \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + y \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + z \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$\begin{cases}
    x + y + 3z = 0 \\
    x + 2y + 4z = 0 \\
    2y + 2z = 0 \\
    x + y +3z = 0
\end{cases}$$

Immediately we see that we can ignore the last equation. Then we can subtract the first one from the second one so we get

$$\begin{cases}
    x + y +3z = 0 \\
    y + z = 0 \\
    2y + 2z = 0
\end{cases}$$

The third one is $2$ times the second one so we can remove it. Finally we have
$$\begin{cases}
    x + y +3z = 0 \\
    y + z = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

Since this is a system of two equations in three unknowns, it has a non-trivial solution and thus, both are linearly dependent. Therefore, the rank is $1$

I must have made some mistake since the answers at the back of the book state that the solution is $2$ but I don't see where I'm wrong

Comment: Do you know the row echelon form? This is a nice method to obtain the rank of any matrix. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form.

Comment: You have gone about this in a very strange way and misinterpreted your findings. Let $M$ be your matrix. You have correctly calculated that the nullity of $M^t$ (the transpose is $M$) is $1$. By the rank-nullity theorem, the rank of $M^t$ is $2$. But the ranks of $M$ and $M^t$ are the same, so the rank of $M$ is also $2$, as the back of the book claims. But this is hardly the best way of finding the rank of $M$: just row-reduce it.

Comment: You're basically left with $2$ linearly independent equations, which means the rank is $2$.

Comment: You are calculating the dimension of the kernel of the transpose, not the rank. Since the former is 1 as you calculated, the latter has to be 2 since they add up to the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Also as a side note you should really learn the Gaussian algorithm, it is way better in general than just throwing equations around

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I found that I just have to reduce it to row echelon form, I guess I misunderstood ranks, the answer is

$$\begin{aligned}
\begin{pmatrix} 
    1 &1 &0 &1 \\ 
    1 &2 &2 &1 \\ 
    3 &4 &2 &3 \end{pmatrix} &\overset{(2) - (1)}{\implies} \\
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &1 &0 &1 \\
    0 &1 &2 &0 \\
    3 &4 &2 &3 
    \end{pmatrix} &\overset{(3)-3\cdot (1)}{\implies} \\
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &1 &0 &1 \\
    0 &1 &2 &0 \\
    0 &1 &2 &0 
    \end{pmatrix} &\overset{(3) - (2)}{\implies} \\
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &1 &0 &1 \\
    0 &1 &2 &0 \\
    0 &0 &0 &0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

Then, since it's in row echelon form it's clear that these are two linearly independent equations

Answer (score 0):

The first two rows are independent  (by inspection: they're not multiples of each other).

Then $r_3=2r_1+r_2$, as you can see.

So the row rank is $2$.  So the rank is  $2$.